# How to NOT to loop in ansible if one of the variable is undefined

Tags: loops, ansible, slack

Here is my script , i am trying to send a message to multiple slack channels, using loops.
I have defined variable inside variable.

```
    - name: send msg to slack
      community.general.slack:
         token: XXXXXXXXXXXX
         blocks:
           - type: section
             text:
              type: mrkdwn
              text: |-
               ****text message********
         channel: '{{ item.slack_channel }}'
         username: 'slackbot'
         parse: 'full'
      loop: "{{ slack | default([]) | selectattr('slack_channel') | list }}"
      when: inventory_hostname ==  'abc.xyz'
```

vars

```
slack:
      - slack_channel: '#mychannel'
      - slack_channel: '{{ slackchannel1|default(None) }}'
      - slack_channel: '{{ slackchannel2|default(None) }}'
```

slackchanne1 and slackchannel2 variable are optional, sometimes i will define value but sometimes i won't define value

What i want is -

When a script is triggered, message has to send to all slack channels, but if the variable is not defined then i don't want loop to run and get fail, incase if it run and no variable found then it should't say play failed, it has to skip that loop cause no value is defined for variable slackchannel1 and slackchannel2 , at the end play should be successful with single defined variable vlaue - **slack_channel: #mychannel**

error i am getting

```
fatal: [abc.xyz]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'msg'\n\nThe error appears to be in 'tasks/slack.yml': line 303, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: send msg to slack\n      ^ here\n"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use *default(None)* to avoid error *"'slackchannel1' is undefined"*

```yaml
    slack:
      - slack_channel: '#mychannel'
      - slack_channel: '{{ slackchannel1|default(None) }}'
      - slack_channel: '{{ slackchannel2|default(None) }}'
```

Then, select defined items

```yaml
loop: "{{ slack | default([]) | selectattr('slack_channel') | list }}"
```

Quoting from [selectattr](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#selectattr)

> If no test is specified, the attribute’s value will be evaluated as a boolean.

---

For example, the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    slack:
      - slack_channel: '#mychannel'
      - slack_channel: '{{ slackchannel1|default(None) }}'
      - slack_channel: '{{ slackchannel2|default(None) }}'

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.slack_channel }}"
      loop: "{{ slack | default([]) | selectattr('slack_channel') | list }}"
```

```sh
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item={'slack_channel': '#mychannel'}) => 
  msg: '#mychannel'
```

When the variable is defined

```sh
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e slackchannel2=test
```

the playbook gives

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item={'slack_channel': '#mychannel'}) => 
  msg: '#mychannel'
ok: [localhost] => (item={'slack_channel': 'test'}) => 
  msg: test
```

Comment: i am getting below error now 

"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'msg'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/tmp/awx_184_z15ueyxz/project/roles/isp/tasks/slack.yml': line 303, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: send msg to slack\n      ^ here\n"

Comment: It works for me. I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: i literally added your suggested solution still getting same error as The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute. Modified my question, added your suggestions (loop)and error i am getting.

Comment: one interesting thing observed is when i run playbook from ansible cli no issues, but when i run from ansible tower (AWX) i am getting error. I have added "survey" to my job template where i define slackchannel1 and slackchannel2 variable values. If i don't define any value in survey then EXTAR VARIABLE section has this slackchannel1: ''

Comment: worked,  i had a typo in my script. Thank you very much for you help @Vladimir Botka